# Unable to enable google oauth2 with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth-2.0, devise, google-oauth

I'm trying to enable OAuth via google. I've configured that callback URL but when trying to authenticate I get an error saying

```
The redirect URI in the request, https://example.com/users/auth/google_oauth2/callback, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client
```

I set Authorized JavaScript origins to `https://example.com` and the redirect to `https://example.com/users/auth/google_oauth2/callback`.

I'm using devise 4.3.3

Comment: The redirect uri should exactly match with that set in Google. Wildcards may not work. Could you please try setting up the complete url in Google i.e. https://example.com/users/auth/google_oauth2/callback

Comment: @PrateekKumarDalbehera That is what I already have

Comment: But the error clearly says that there is a mismatch in the redirect uri. It starts with example.com??

Answer (score 0):

I would aim to trace HTTPS messages so that you can see exactly what is being sent over the wire - use a tool such as Fiddler or Charles.

Standard messages for a Web UI look like those from [my write up](https://authguidance.com/2017/09/26/basicspa-oauthworkflow/). Google messages will be equivalent.

Hopefully this approach will enable you to resolve your own problem. If not then please update your question with full HTTP message details